# tomcat wont start up on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I'm new to Linux but having spent a whole day I Installed Java and Tomcat. My goal is to host an App with this Linux box. I know it all works fine from my windows based machine, but it is my laptop so I'm planning to use the Linux Box as my dedicated server.

Following many many forums I've now got Tomcat 7 installed. However i cannot get it to start.

Changing to the tomcat directory and "./startup.sh" i get the following output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE: /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:  /usr/local/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME: usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/
Using CLASSPATH: /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

That's the end of the output.

However localhost:8080 is not up, and in the tomcat log file is the error "eval: 1: usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun//bin/java: not found"

Hopefully there is some expert here who can help me with this problem. Please note that I'm a novice when it comes to Linux.

PS: My Linux version is Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JRE_HOME is missing a `/` at the start of it.

Your CATALINA_HOME and CLASSPATH also looks wrong, with a `local.tomcat` instead of a `local/tomcat` and `c\tomcat-juli` instead of `tomcat-juli`

Comment: hi stephen thanks. how do i go about correcting that? like i said im new to linux and just installing java itself was a mission. has it got something to do with the java class /environment path? coz that was a problem which i think i corrected with help of forums which were all different. how do i go about that?                                                                oh and those were typos sorry. i havent figured out how to copy from the terminal window yet so i typed it haha. edited now

Comment: It shouldn't end in a / either. I'm not sure where you've specified the JRE_HOME value to use, possibly in /etc/environment

Comment: if anyone else has this problem i used this to fix it.. in terminal; sudo bash -c "echo JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/ >> /etc/environment" ;; also note that set JAVA_HOME=<<your java path here>>.. once you've done this you needa reboot the comp. you can check if you were successful with this; echo $JAVA_HOME;

Answer (score 4):

Try typing this on the command line:

```
$ export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
$ export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
$ /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

This will run Tomcat in the terminal you have open, so you can watch it do stuff. Press CTRL+C to quit it.

Answer (score 1):

1. First download the Linux tomcat version.
2. Unzip it.
3. Go to the tomcat bin folder.
4. Run the startup.sh for start the tomcat server
5. Shutdown.sh for using to stop the tomcat

see the link,
http://brigitzblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/linux-how-can-i-startstop-tomcat-server.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm just posting in case this will help someone else. I had my `JAVA_HOME` set to

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java`

I should have been

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre`

without the `/bin/java` part at the end. This is because will look for `bin/java` in that path already and you don't need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

When I encountered something similar, the problems was with my Tomcat7 installation.  I downgraded to Tomcat6 and it started working perfectly.